# how to get url for django url include without name

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have the following main site urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',


   (r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),

)
```

I need to call this from a link, but this type of entry has no name I can with something like:

```
<a href="{% url 'search???' %}">Go To Search</a>
```

How can I call this url entry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django haystack urls are already named:

https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/urls.py

So you can use:

```
<a ref={% url "haystack_search" %}>search page</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
<a href='/appname/search'>Go To Search</a>
```